# DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, invalidoperationexception

I have a custom control inherited from `DataGridView` that I'd like to be able to just copy the .cs file for, and drop it in to any project. There's one bit of code that I can't manage to move out of `Main.cs`, and into `DataGridView.cs` though:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    dgv.Columns[0].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void InitLayout()
    {
        base.InitLayout();
        Sort(Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        Columns[0].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
    }

    // Lots of methods snipped
}
```

The program immediately throws an `InvalidOperationException` on the `Sort()`:

> DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted.

How can I move this code into `DataGridView.cs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public MyDataGridView()
    {
        base.DataBindingComplete += Sort;
    }

    public void Sort(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sort(Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        Columns[0].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
    }
}
```